# BDS2006, C++: How to make own form template for creating dialogs?

Tags: ide, c++builder

When you create dialog in BDS IDE it's derived from TForm class and it's just an empty form. As our system has a GUI standard for how all forms should look like it would be nice to make a template and use it as a base for future dialogs instead of plain TForm.

For example all our dialogs have our custom component with buttons aligned to the right edge, spacing 10 px between them, etc. Or icon with company's logo which always is in the same place. Or only close button X visible, no minimize or maximize. Now whenever I need to add new dialog I choose New/Form and have to place all needed components and settings by hand. Possibility to define template would be timesaver and we wouldn't have to remember about all of these standard details.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Visual Form Inheritance](http://www.webtechcorp.co.uk/web-developer-training-delphi-article-vfi-1.htm).